# Issue with Colomn count in CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Columns should fill with height constraint. It is working fine in Chrome but not in IE and Firefox.

In `IE` and `firefox` it is distributing evenly instead of taking the height of the column. I have total 16 sub `divs`, I want them to come in 5 5 5 1. It is working fine in `chrome` (5 5 5 1) not in `firefox` and `IE` (4 4 4 4)

Here is my Code -

```
<div class="example">
    <div class="example-auto">1A</div>
    <div class="example-auto">1B</div>
    <div class="example-auto">1C</div>
    <div class="example-auto">1D</div>
    <div class="example-auto">2A</div>
    <div class="example-auto">2B</div>
    <div class="example-auto">2C</div>
    <div class="example-auto">2D</div>
    <div class="example-auto">3A</div>
    <div class="example-auto">3B</div>
    <div class="example-auto">3C</div>
    <div class="example-auto">3D</div>
    <div class="example-auto">4A</div>
    <div class="example-auto">4A</div>
    <div class="example-auto">4A</div>
    <div class="example-auto">4A</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.example {
  -webkit-columns: 4;
  -moz-columns: 4;
  columns: 4;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.example-auto {
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give **column-fill: auto;** in the same class where you give     **columns: 4;**
Don't need to give it in child class.

```
.example {
  -webkit-columns: 4;
  -moz-columns: 4;
  columns: 4;
    height:100px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0 0.5em;
   -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

You can check example here.
http://jsfiddle.net/VijayDhanvai/0r600sg2/